Puppeteer "Failed to launch the browser process!"
Using the eckinox/pdf-bundle in Symfony 6.4, I'm hitting an issue when calling he node script which calls Puppeteer.
2024-07-03T11:03:39.923Z puppeteer:browsers:launcher Launched 7250
2024-07-03T11:03:40.026Z puppeteer:browsers:launcher Trying to kill 7250
2024-07-03T11:03:40.026Z puppeteer:browsers:launcher Browser process 7250 exists
    /home/platform.company.com/public_html/node_modules/@puppeteer/browsers/lib/cjs/launch.js:310
                reject(new Error([
                       ^

Error: Failed to launch the browser process!


TROUBLESHOOTING: https://pptr.dev/troubleshooting

    at Interface.onClose (/home/platform.company.com/public_html/node_modules/@puppeteer/browsers/lib/cjs/launch.js:310:24)
    at Interface.emit (node:events:531:35)
    at Interface.close (node:internal/readline/interface:528:10)
    at Socket.onend (node:internal/readline/interface:254:10)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:531:35)
    at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1696:12)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)

Node.js v20.15.0

I've stripped the whole thing back to just this command (to find the Chrome version) which produces the same error.
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async()=>{const x = require("puppeteer"); console.log(await(await(await x.launch()).newPage()).browser().version())})()

If I execute the js from command line, it works fine. Both use the same user, environment variables and permissions. The difference is that the PHP bundle calls node from EXEC.

This question is similar to: Error: Failed to launch the browser process puppeteer. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem. Can you share your PHP code and composer.json as a [mcve]?

I decided to give up on this path and instead implemented Snappy (which works great).
